# passing arrays with advanced rest client chrome plugin

Tags: rest, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying out chrome-extension advanced rest client app, but when I send something like:

```
http://myDom:34234/my/path/method?param=["{a-guid}"]
```

the actual parameter arrives on the server as "[\"{a-guid}\"]" how do I get it to send the array as an array rather than a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper URL for this request should looks like:

```
http://myDom:34234/my/path/method?param=%5B%22%7Ba-guid%7D%22%5D
```

All URLs must be encoded. 
In the app you can expand URL panel and under "Query parameters" section encode values to proper form.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your server implementation (e.g. php, c#, rails, javascript, python, etc).

all headers arrive on the server as a string. it's up to the application to parse that string into a native object (e.g. an array) in that language.

in the php world, here's the code we use:

`parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $args);`

---

**update:**

based on your comment below i suggest you use new JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString)

You need System.Web.Extensions dll for the same and import the following namespace.

Namespace: System.Web.Script.Serialization

for more info [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Comment: it's a c# asp.net application, I was just mimic-ing the call the app was making which does get received and interpreted as an array of strings, just that when I send it from advanced rest client app it takes the whole thing as a string